# Android queried adapter reset

Tags: android, arrays, json, listview, android-adapter

Is it possible to reset my adapter to original state, without make a new query?

**For example**

I have `JSONArray`, that I cut some of records to show selected in `ListView`, but I want to reset data and show all records again. Does that possible?

```
private JSONArray modifyJsonArray(JSONArray array, final Integer param) throws JSONException {
    List<JSONObject> jsons = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        Integer statusId = Integer.parseInt(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("statusId"));
        if (statusId == param){
            jsons.add(array.getJSONObject(i));
        }
    }
    return new JSONArray(jsons);
}


private void selectStatus(JSONArray arr, Integer param) throws JSONException {
    myArr= modifyJsonArray(arr, param);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I have a spinner with all statusId and option "All". When all is selected I need to show all records.I have choose status id from simple spinner, and just call `selectStatus(myArr, statusId)` The problem is when I remove records from array, I cannot restore it back.

Comment: For that you need to keep your main list separate in one variable and filter should be apply on this variable's another copy, so on reset time you can directly reset it from main variable.

Comment: Can you show any example code?

Comment: Show me your code here so I will help you in it only

Comment: @Vickyexpert posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now read below instruction and follow it for your solution,

**First Create on Variable Outside methods as like below,**

```
 List<JSONObject> mainJsons = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
```

**Now modify your method for modifyJsonArray as below**

```
  private JSONArray modifyJsonArray(JSONArray array, final Integer param) throws JSONException 
  {
      List<JSONObject> jsons = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
      mainJsons = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

      for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) 
      {
          Integer statusId = Integer.parseInt(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("statusId"));

          mainJsons.add(array.getJSONObject(i));

          if (statusId == param)
          {
              jsons.add(array.getJSONObject(i));
          }
      }

     return new JSONArray(jsons);
  }
```

**Now create one method for reset main array as below**

```
  private void resetStatus(JSONArray arr) throws JSONException 
  {
      if(arr != null && arr. size() > 0)
      {
           myArr = arr;
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
  }
```

**Now call this method as below where you want to reset listviw**

```
  resetStatus(new JSONArray(mainJsons));
```

Comment: First mainJsons is not JSONArray > resetStatus(mainJsons, param); Second the problem is myArr= modifyJsonArray(arr, param); in this peace of code, which change jsonarray

Comment: Working, but it param is passed, and want to restore full list. Now it restores list with some param.

Comment: I have three items with different statusId. When I do query I see only one item. My target is to restore all items (let say on button click)

Comment: For that you need to put here your adapter code as you are passing param in adapter so put your code here for adapter

Comment: The issue is I have a spinner with all statusId and option "All". When all is selected I need to show all records

Comment: Ya therefore asking show me your adapter code so I can manipulate code according to it

Comment: Then sorry but I would not be able to help you as without seeing your adapter code I can't give you any suggestion

Comment: I believe problem is not in adapter, but in changing myArr

Comment: see you are working on param value and also you are passing that param in adapter so how you are using param in adapter that I need to know otherwise how can I manage param for "All" option

Comment: And one more thing when you are getting proper data using param from array then why you are passing again param in adapter ?

Comment: I don't know what that means

Comment: I do not use param in adapter. I have show all code that I use to apply param. Adapter just get me full json

Comment: Yes, that's it. That parameter is not passed to adapter

Comment: The most interesting part is now, when I do two queries it returns to first one, not to all

Comment: I query to param 1, then query to param 2. Then reset and it returns not all recurds, but query 1 records

Comment: It's not possible as we have taken entire separate variable as "mainJsons" and it is everytime initialize and assign new values on each query so it should always entire data